# Gratuitous parentheses around expression in Visual Studio

Tags: javascript, visual-studio

I am getting this message in quite of bit of places in Visual Studio all of a sudden.

> Gratuitous parentheses around expression.

I am OK with validationg my Javascript but what does it mean and why is the expressions below causing this?

```
if ((self.display.current() !== display.LOSER && self.display.current() !== display.WINNER) || !self.bye()) {

}
```

> Visual Studio 15.8.6

Comment: That just means you've got unnecessary parentheses around your expression. I'm not sure why that would show up on this expression however it might be worth putting down the version of Visual Studio/ESLint as it might be a bug. There is a way to disable ESLint completely if that's one solution for your case that you're willing to do.

Comment: Operator precedence means that `&&` is evaluated before `||` making the parentheses around `(self.display.current() !== display.LOSER && self.display.current() !== display.WINNER)` redundant, although it does make it "easier" to read.

Comment: Do you mean the following wouldn't group the `||` with the other conditional statment.  I have had issues with JS not doing the order correctly so I put the `()` to make sure it does. `self.display.current() !== display.LOSER && self.display.current() !== display.WINNER || !self.bye()`

Comment: Parenthesis aid readability.
I cannot believe someone was dumb enough to actually dream up that check and manage to get it included. Had a to be a joke that no one picked up on.

Answer (score 0):

**This rule has a string option:**

- `"all"` (default) disallows unnecessary parentheses around any expression
- `"functions"` disallows unnecessary parentheses only around function expressions

**This rule has an object option for exceptions to the "all" option:**

- `"conditionalAssign"`: false allows extra parentheses around assignments in conditional test expressions
- `"returnAssign"`: false allows extra parentheses around assignments in return statements
- `"nestedBinaryExpressions"`: false allows extra parentheses in nested binary expressions

**Compare these two codes:**

Examples of **incorrect** code for this rule with the default `"all"` option:

```
/* eslint no-extra-parens: "error" */

a = (b * c);
(a * b) + c;
typeof (a);
(function(){} ? a() : b());
```

Examples of **correct** code for this rule with the default `"all"` option:

```
/* eslint no-extra-parens: "error" */

(0).toString();
({}.toString.call());
(function(){}) ? a() : b();
(/^a$/).test(x);
```

And Your code correct format is

```
self.display.current() !== display.LOSER && self.display.current() !== display.WINNER || !self.bye()
```